# Replace negative values by NA values

Tags: r, conditional-statements, missing-data, assign

I have positive, negative and `NA` values in a Table, I need to replace negative values by `NA` values. Positive and `NA` values should remain as they are in Table. My Data set is similar to the one below:

```
NO. q
1   NA
2   NA
3   -133.6105198
4   -119.6991209
5   28.84460104
6   66.05345087
7   84.7058947
8   -134.4522694
9   NA
10  NA
11  73.20465643
12  -69.90723514
13  NA
14  69.70833003
15  65.27859906
```

I tried this:

```
if (q>0) {
    q=NA
} else {
    q=q
}
```

Comment: data is like this: here "q" name of column
NA
NA
-133.6105198
-119.6991209
28.84460104
66.05345087
84.7058947
-134.4522694
NA
NA
73.20465643
-69.90723514
NA
69.70833003
65.27859906

Comment: Hi and thanks for the question. Since you are a new user, you'd probably like to read the Tour and also either accept the answer that covers you the most (green tick next to each answer), or provide additional information if no answer covers you 100%.

Answer (score 12):

Or use `replace`:

```
> df$q2 <- replace(df$q, which(df$q < 0), NA)
> df
   NO.          q       q2
1    1         NA       NA
2    2         NA       NA
3    3 -133.61052       NA
4    4 -119.69912       NA
5    5   28.84460 28.84460
6    6   66.05345 66.05345
7    7   84.70589 84.70589
8    8 -134.45227       NA
9    9         NA       NA
10  10         NA       NA
11  11   73.20466 73.20466
12  12  -69.90724       NA
13  13         NA       NA
14  14   69.70833 69.70833
15  15   65.27860 65.27860
```

Or with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[q < 0, q := NA]
```

Or with replace in a dplyr pipe:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(q = replace(q, which(q<0), NA))
```

Comment: How do I adjust the dplyr solution that it applies to the whole dataset?

Comment: `mutate(across(everything(), function(x){replace(x, which(x<0), NA)}))`

Answer (score 9):

You could try this:

```
sample <- c(1, -2, NA)
sample[sample < 0] <- NA
sample
[1]  1 NA NA
```

Or if you're using a `data.frame` (suppose it's called `df`):

```
df$q[df$q < 0] <- NA
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try

```
df1$q1 <- NA^(df1$q <0) * df1$q
df1
#   NO.          q       q1
#1    1         NA       NA
#2    2         NA       NA
#3    3 -133.61052       NA
#4    4 -119.69912       NA
#5    5   28.84460 28.84460
#6    6   66.05345 66.05345
#7    7   84.70589 84.70589
#8    8 -134.45227       NA
#9    9         NA       NA
#10  10         NA       NA
#11  11   73.20466 73.20466
#12  12  -69.90724       NA 
#13  13         NA       NA
#14  14   69.70833 69.70833
#15  15   65.27860 65.27860
```

Or use `ifelse`

```
 with(df1, ifelse(q < 0, NA, q))
```

Or

```
 is.na(df1$q) <- df1$q < 0
```

Comment: q[which(q < 0)] <- NA

Comment: @TikaRamGurung You can use any of the solutions to get the result, `which` is not necesssary `q[q<0] <- NA` would also work as shown by naltipar

Answer (score 1):

Another way of accomplishing the same thing is (now I see this is ALMOST the same as another answer by akrun, sorry for that)

```
daf$q = ifelse(daf$q < 0, NA_real_, daf$q)
```